# ExpressJS static file serve always serves the same file

Tags: node.js, express, static, router

I have a expressJs setup which looks like this:

```
// Imports...
const app: express.Application = express();
const port: number = 3001;

const listener = new StatementListenerAPI();
app.use('/listen', listener.getRouter());

app.use('/welcome', router);


if (fs.existsSync('./client')) {
    // Running in prod environment with pre built client directory. Serve this.
    app.use(express.static('./client'));
}

app.listen(port);
```

So I have some routers connected to the express app, and at the bottom I declare that the directory `client` should be served statically. This directory contains an index.html as well as lots of JS, CSS and PNG files. However, no matter which URL I try to access from the express server, it always shows the code of the index.html within the statically served directory. The references to the JS and CSS files used inside the index.html also just return the code of the index.html.

I am using ExpressJS 4.16.3

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: So technically it works if using `__dirname + '/client'` instead of `./client`. What I am now getting is that, when making GET requests from e.g. Postman (therefore "hand-crafting" the HTTP requests), I am always getting the correct results. If I call the resources from within my web browser, it still always shows the website (resolves the index.html). However, now all resources like JS and CSS scripts are being resolved properly, so apperantly Chrome resolves those dependencies properly, I am just wondering why I am still getting the contents of index.html as result when requesting some of the assets or some of the express endpoints via Chrome. API calls via code are working fine, so its only why manual chrome requests show this weird behaviour, at this point I am only asking out of curiosity.

Comment: What is the function `serveStatic`? Why don't you use the built in `express.static`? Also the path supplied to `express.static` should be relative to the directory from where you launch your node process or an absolute path.

Comment: ```serveStatic``` was a seperate library I've tried, I had the same results using ```express.static```. I forgot to switch back the the express variant for the question. The suggestion with the absolute path worked, thanks! I have updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer to your original question:**

The path supplied to `express.static` should be relative to the directory from where you launch your node process or an absolute path. To be safe construct an absolute path (ie from the current directory or file). For example:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/client'));
```

**Regarding your followup question:**

I assume this is because Chrome uses heavy caching and it thinks this folder should return the html file. You can try and [reset all caches in Chrome](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32050?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en), or just for the page.

Comment: For path operations I recommend using path module
const path = require('path')
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client')))

Comment: The caches could actually be the cause. I'll try if that is the cause.